# Use SPI pins from ASP.NET Core application on RaspberryPi 3

Tags: windows-iot, spi, c#, web

In my project I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows IoT OS, and I have a RC522 RFID reader. I would like to use this component (RC522) from my ASP.NET Core application.

I would like to use [this](https://github.com/mlowijs/mfrc522-netmf/tree/master/Mfrc522) library in this project, because I have some experience with this library.

If it is not possible to use this than what should I use to read my RC522 using SPI pins?

Answer (score 1):

The [mfrc522-netmf code](https://github.com/mlowijs/mfrc522-netmf/blob/master/Mfrc522/Mfrc522Lib/Mfrc522.cs) is build for the MicroFramework and its not the code but the PIN numbering that is not compatible withe the Raspberry Pi

One way is try and copy the code into your project and just replace all the `Cpu.Pin` with the actual RaspberryPi specific static ones.

That code "should" then be able to work on the SPI since the SPI is the same implementation on any device.

For more infomration on working with SPI you can [look at this](http://www.iot-developer.net/windows-iot/uwp-programming-in-c/spi/rpi-using-the-spi-interface) to see how it communicates on IoT on the Pi - There is [more information on the SPI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.spi) here and a whole [bunch of samples here](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples)

It not really that difficult to port it over you may just need to invest some time for it. And when you do get it working, please consider pushing your code to the IoT github or host it your self. More people can use it and improve it then.

[**A good sample is here - Try and follow how the SPI device is used.**](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/blob/develop/SPIAccelerometer/CS/MainPage.xaml.cs) - In particular the `InitSPIAccel` method.

Comment: Thanks for the lot of useful links!
My main problem is that I can not use `Windows.Devices.Spi` namespace in my ASP .NET Core project. I found some wrapper classes for `Windows.Devices.Gpio` and `Windows.Devices.I2C` ([this](https://github.com/jeremylindsayni/Bifrost)) but I have not found for SPI yet.

Comment: Errrrr.... I missed that. ASP.NET Core? Core? Maybe I have not heard the news but can you do that on IoT? I thought you can only build Universal Applications.. You can probably get a RaspberryPi package then and it will have all of that.

Comment: Please give me the tutorial you followed or some indication. I am not sure this is possible. Winodws IoT runs on .NET and Windows 10 API

Comment: I have found [this article](https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2017/04/22/hosting-a-net-core-2-web-api-instance-on-the-raspberry-pi-3/) for how to run ASP.NET Core on Windows IoT (I have not tried yet). For controlling the GPIO pins from ASP.NET Core application [here](https://github.com/jeremylindsayni/Bifrost) are some wrapper (for GPIO, I2C but no for SPI :( )

Comment: And [here is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Keze2Gz8TB0) a useful video too!

Comment: Wow.. that is freaking awesome! :D But obviolsy you have this problem of GPIO. I am sure you can just download a NuGet Package for the Rasbperry Pi GPIO and all the SPI stuff into core? Those are the same packages used in the Universal Applications.